# Watermark in 64-bit AviSynth+

Tags: plugins, avisynth

The `Watermark` filter listed in the [AviSynth External filters page](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/External_filters#As_Yet_Unclassified) works for 32-bit. On my 64-bit machine, after downloading, extracting, and playing the example file in the [filter page](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1554560#post1554560), I see:

```
Cannot load a 32 bit DLL in 64 bit Avisynth: '/path/to/extracted/directory/Watermark.dll'. (/path/to/extracted/directory/example.avs, line1)
```

The first line of `example.avs` has:

```
Load_Stdcall_plugin("Watermark.dll")
```

Does an equivalent plugin exist for 64-bit AviSynth+?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are talking about the Watermark2 filter, the [AviSynth wiki page for the filter](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Watermark2) has for download a 64-bit, AviSynth+ version of the filter.